# .htaccess redirect all old URL to new subfolder URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

We have a multilingual website with three languages: Flemish, Dutch and French. The main language doesn't have a subfolder, the rest does. So it look something like this:

1. Flemish: website.com/...
2. Dutch: website.com/nl/...
3. French: website.com/fr/...

We would like to give the main language (Flemish) a subfolder as well. The URL structure will look like this: http://website.com/be/...

I was wondering if there was an easy way - using the htaccess file - to 301 redirect all the old Flemish URLs (website.com/...) to the new version (website.com/be/...)? URL rewriting is probably faster than redirecting each URL invidually.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this to redirect URL

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^website.com.*$ http://website.com/be/ [R=301,L]
```